# How to encapsulate definitions into a class? (Use const and then scope it)

Tags: php, c++

All my PHP files conform to class.className.php as a naming conventoin.  So I put all my definitions in a class called class.Configure.php like below.  Is there a best practice way to put this in an acutal class.  Consistency makes it easier for me to manage my code.

This is the only "loose" code I have in my library.

I guess the actual question is should I put this code in a class? I would like to unless I'm breaking some sort of best practice.

Also in C++ the preprocessor comes through and replaces all you #defines with the actual values before compilation.  So I atleast undertand the concept of definitions in C++..they are simple text substitutions before compilation.

Is it the sameway in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's [class constants<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

```
class MyClass
{
    const constant = 'constant value';

    public function showConstant() {
        echo  self::constant . "\n";
    }
}

echo MyClass::constant . "\n";
```

Comment: Note that class-constants may only have static values.